# How to move a string up based on the first character of the line?

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to get the content of all the rows of the text file in Python that doesn't start with the number to move to the first upper row that started with number as shown in the example below:

The data in the file looks like this

```
1   Bananas and Tea 25
2   Chocolate
and Tea 24
3   Ice cream
4 Bread, sour cream,
socks
and pants 45
```

What I am trying to achieve is to modify the data in the file to this:

```
1   Bananas and Tea 25
2   Chocolate and Tea 24
3   Ice cream
4   Bread, sour cream, socks and pants 45
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex is your friend for this:

```
>>> input = "1   Bananas and Tea 25\n2   Chocolate \nand Tea 24\n3   Ice cream\n4 Bread, sour cream, \nsocks \nand pants 45"
>>> re.sub("\n(?![0-9]+)", "", input)
'1   Bananas and Tea 25\n2   Chocolate and Tea 24\n3   Ice cream\n4 Bread, sour cream, socks and pants 45'
```